# Unix Date command using

Tags: shell, date, unix, datetime, unix-timestamp

I workout hardly to solve then program help on it

```
T=`date + %k`
if [ $t –ge 0 –a $t –le 12 ];
then
    echo “Good Morning”
elif[ $t –ge 12 –a $t –le 14 ];
then
    echo “Good Afternoon”
elif[ $t –ge 14 –a $t –le 18 ];
then
    echo “Good Evening"
else
    echo “Good night”
fi
```

Output: [:date unexpected operator

Comment: (1) Your T's should all be the same case (you assign `T` but use `$t`). (2) you must have a space between `elif` and `[`.

Comment: Yes, but the error comes before that. It needs to be `date +%k`, no space between `+` and `%k`

Comment: @mjsqu that's why I gave a comment, not an answer. What I cited will be problems.

Comment: Also, those dashes look quite long, did you copy this from MS Word or another word processing application? The dashes need to be `-`.

Comment: Also the double quotes aren't plain double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=`date +%k`
if [ $t -ge 0 -a $t -le 12 ];
then
  echo "Good Morning"
elif [ $t -ge 12 -a $t -le 14 ];
then
  echo "Good Afternoon"
elif [ $t -ge 14 -a $t -le 18 ];
then
  echo "Good Evening"
else
  echo "Goodnight"
fi
```